# С какой сис таблицей нужно добавить связь чтобы увидеть имя таблицы: Select Table_Name

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT Table_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions      s
    LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses     sp
       ON COALESCE(s.session_id,99999)  = sp.spid
    LEFT JOIN sys.databases        d
       ON COALESCE(s.database_id,99999) = d.database_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r
        ON COALESCE(r.session_id,99999)  = sp.spid
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(COALESCE(r.sql_handle, sp.sql_handle)) t
WHERE d.[name] = 'BI_EXECT_DB'
```

Comment: Вы про sys.objects?

Comment: Имя какой именно таблицы вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: Список таблиц, которые относятся к датабазе 'BI_EXECT_DB'.

Comment: Приведенный запрос не имеет отношения к заголовку. Я уверен, что где-то здесь вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86)

Answer (score 0):

```
USE BI_EXECT_DB

GO

SELECT  s.name AS SchemaName,
        t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
ORDER BY s.name, t.name
```